# Where to instantiate beanfactory in java project

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java and Spring world, so please bear with me. I am working on my first java project. Here I am using Spring framework, creating an object from `ApplicationContext`.

I have multiple files in the project in different packages such as *dao, lib, util,* etc. My question is where should following lines go. I will be creating objects of multiple classes  at various places using similar code as given below. Should I use them wherever I need an object of 'OrganizationMapperService' or some other class? What is the standard way to do this?

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

OrganizationMapperService orgMapperService = 
    (OrganizationMapperService) context.getBean("organizationMapperService");
```

Comment: NEVER create an instance of the applicationcontext. You are creating a new instance each time. You should only have a single instance of the context everything else should be dependency injected.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes, That was looking wrong, How to do dependency injection, can you give some sample link/code, I looked it up and got more confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a web app, you should configure the app context loader in the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-*.xml,classpath:context/visibility-applicationContext.xml,classpath:eventbus-applicationContext.xml,classpath:context/clients-applicationContext-ws.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I am doing it in a jar, which will be used as a dependency in the web app, will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

The references which you want to inject during container loading can be declared as beans in application context file as follows :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.name"></context:component-scan>

<bean id="abc" class=" package.name.Abc" />
```

component-scan will automatically scan for components.

Now you can Autowire the reference in class iin which you want to use it as follows :

```
@Autowired
private Abc abc
```

You need to make entry in web.xml for the applicationContext file.

Comment: It starts to give error: `Autowired members must be defined in the valid spring bean(@Component/@Service,etc.)`

Comment: @saurabh Can you just post the actual error that you are getting